# Problem with Keras Functional API using class to define a model

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I was trying to make a function for dense layer in keras for specifying number of units as per my requirement and it returned an object just as it would do when storing constant object in variable, but I don't know why this throws error.

I have tried both lambda function and the usual function notation, none work.

I am using Google Colab (tensorflow == 2.2.0)

Here is the code to regenerate the error:

```py
class Model(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense10 = lambda k : tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

  def den8(self, c):
      return tf.keras.layers.Dense(c, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    inputs = keras.Input(342)
    den = self.den8(4)                 # -- USING usual function
    # den = self.dense10(4)            # -- USING lambda function
    x = den(inputs)
    if training:
      x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return self.dense2(x)


model = Model()
model.compile(loss='mse',metrics=['acc'])
model(np.array(list(range(342))))
model.summary()
```

And the complete error message:

```py
Model: "model_22"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-f64f7a465276> in <module>()
     24 model.compile(loss='mse',metrics=['acc'])
     25 model(np.array(list(range(342))))
---> 26 model.summary()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in summary(self, line_length, positions, print_fn)
   1352                               line_length=line_length,
   1353                               positions=positions,
-> 1354                               print_fn=print_fn)
   1355 
   1356   def _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/layer_utils.py in print_summary(model, line_length, positions, print_fn)
    251   for i in range(len(layers)):
    252     if sequential_like:
--> 253       print_layer_summary(layers[i])
    254     else:
    255       print_layer_summary_with_connections(layers[i])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/layer_utils.py in print_layer_summary(layer)
    209     name = layer.name
    210     cls_name = layer.__class__.__name__
--> 211     fields = [name + ' (' + cls_name + ')', output_shape, layer.count_params()]
    212     print_row(fields, positions)
    213 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in count_params(self)
   1879                          ', but the layer isn\'t built. '
   1880                          'You can build it manually via: `' + self.name +
-> 1881                          '.build(batch_input_shape)`.')
   1882     return layer_utils.count_params(self.weights)
   1883 

ValueError: You tried to call `count_params` on dense_46, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: `dense_46.build(batch_input_shape)`.
```

Please help me resolve this issue!

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a layer defined similar to `self.dense1`?

Comment: In that way I will have to define many objects in the __init__ function, so I thought this to be an easy way to go around by creating a function and passing the required number of units, also it looked clean when handling multiple dense objects.

Comment: That is the core of the issue. You cannot create a new layer inside the call function, since call can only work on existing variables. Every time you create a new layer inside call, you create a new set of variables as well.

Comment: Okay, got that! One workaround may be by defining a function instead of a class as I have discovered, thanks for clarification.

Comment: If you define a function, dynamic content such as `if` statements won't be executed after the model is created, only during creation. So when you call `model()`, it will ALWAYS use dropout. To run inference, you'll need to use `model.predict()` or `model(..., training=False)`. Both trigger the default behaviour of the `Dropout` layer, but don't run the `if`.

Comment: Does this even apply to eager execution in tensorflow 2 (which is on by default)? In this there is no graph of model, so no static model. Am I thinking correct, and what about pytorch which has always been eage sort of??

Comment: Eager execution creates a graph on first call from all functions that were used in the call. PyTorch does the same. During this first call, if the `if` in the graph resolves to `True`, only the graph for that branch will be created, unless you use the TF equivalent (eg. `tf.cond`). Variables and ops in the other branch won't be initialized.

Comment: This, however, is only partially true for the `call` method of `Model`. In that case, the variables are fixed, defined in the built model. Therefore, it guarantees that no new variables will be required even if the graph needs to be rebuilt. Therefore, you can use branch statements directly in the `call` method of a `Model`.

Comment: Your approach in the question goes against this guarantee that tensorflow expects in subclasses of `Model`.

Comment: I did research these many days about model and graph generation in both Pytorch and Tensorflow, now that I read your comments, they make complete sense. Now I know where I went wrong, thanks for help!! :)